# Cover photo duplication issue via Facebook app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

When I try to update/change my cover photos via Facebook mobile app (iOS) a copy is being created as a cover photo without retaining likes and comments. These are previously set cover photos in cover photos album on my Facebook account.

I'm not doing a new upload from the device. Such duplication doesn't happen when I try it via Facebook app on Android, Facebook mobile site and Facebook on PC. It only occurs via Facebook app on my iPhone. I've also tried it on several iPhones which all have the latest version Facebook mobile app and operating systems.

Do you also have the same issue on your iPhones? Is this a sort of bug or glitch? What could be the reason of this? I couldn't see any posts regarding such issue on the internet either.

Comment: File a bug with FB in their app > help > file a bug.

Comment: @ankii, thanks for your comment. I was wondering if you also have the same issue? Have you tried it on iPhone? Just to understand how common this issue is.

Comment: Oh, I don't use it :)